# Rails - How to use Squeel to search through associated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, squeel

I think this is a simple question:

I have a Building model and each Building **has_one** city and each city **belongs_to** Buildings. I'd like to perform a search on the Building's city name (not the id) using Squeel.

Currently I have:

```
where{(zip =~ "%#{search}%") | (Building.all.map(&:city) =~ "%#{search}%")}
```

The searching through zip codes works fine since that is a direct attribute for the Building model. It's the second clause I am struggling with.

Right now, I get this error:

```
Cannot visit NilClass
```

How Can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join the city table to filter on the city field.

```
where{(zip =~ "%#{search}%") | (city.name =~ "%#{search}%")}.joins{city.outer}
```

*If all buildings have one city you can remove the outer join.*

Comment: Just tried this and got: PGError: ERROR:  column buildings.city does not exist -- I did: ".joins{city}" without ".outer" since every building has one city

Comment: I just changed the query. Is it better now?